# CSV into list in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have imported a `.csv` file into Python and named it `data`. It looks something like this:

```
aK    bK    id
.124  .121  1
.320  .202  2
.222  .198  3
```

And so on for a few hundred rows. How do I convert column `aK` and column `bK` into lists? I have tried this:

```
aK = []
for row in data:
    aK.append(row[0])
```

But aK is still a blank list.

Comment: how u imported csv in data??

Comment: Can you clarify that question please

Comment: @japem I think he's asking how you loaded the file and converted it to a python string/list/other object. Were you using the `csv` module?

Comment: Oh. Yes I was. >>> Import csv >>> a = open('MyFile.csv') >>> data = csv.reader(a)

Comment: @japem For the code you've posted in comment it's hard to belive `aK` is empty after the loop, post the actual code in question body.(Perhaps you consumed the file object before you passed it to `csv.reader`)

Comment: What you did should have worked. Can you `print row[0];print row[1]` so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary ok, so you are right. I got the code I posted in the question to work, but only after reimporting the file. I had before tried to run the code >>> for row in data: >>> print row, which didn't print anything. I don't know why it did that, but after doing that, nothing that I did with the table actually changed anything. So I reimported the table and ran the code from my question, and it worked. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv

CSV_FILE = "test.csv"

def main():
    with open(CSV_FILE) as inf:
        in_csv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
        header = next(in_csv)       # skip header row
        ak, bk, id = zip(*in_csv)   # get columns

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which gives

```
ak = ('.124', '.320', '.222')
bk = ('.121', '.202', '.198')
id = ('1', '2', '3')
```

Comment: Is the "test.csv" file the one I originally imported?

Comment: @Hackaholic - Why reinvent the wheel?  Importing a module is trivial in Python.  Besides, the `csv` module will be more robust than anything handcrafted.

Comment: @iCodez this 4 line of code, i dont think reinvent the whell, and all this csv module make use of this built function like split and strip only

Comment: @HughBothwell I can see why you looked for `delimiter=" "` skipping initial spaces. That makes sense for the data on this website but I think it's very likely OP had used a tab delimited file and Stackoverflow converted them to spaces or the text editor did

Answer (score 0):

The way you approached it seems fine. You just didn't show how you created `data`

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('data.csv') as f:
        aK, bK = [], []
        next(f) # skip headers
        for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'):
            aK.append(float(row[0]))
            bK.append(float(row[1]))


'aK\tbK\tid\n'
>>> aK
[0.124, 0.32, 0.222]
>>> bK
[0.121, 0.202, 0.198]
```